# How are mathematical properties discovered and proved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider property of the logarithm:

$$\log_{b}x^n = n\cdot \log_{b}x$$

My question is, how was this property (and in general, any other property in mathematics) discovered and proved?

Did they just try using random values of $x$,$n$ and $b$ until they realized that property above holds no matter what values we use, or there is an algebraic way of proving it?

Comment: In the example you gave is almost trivial to prove once you already understand well the definition of logarithm. In general, I'd expect that many basic properties are shown as rather straightforward results from the very definition or almost, whereas deeper, more complex properties may require more work.

Comment: This is a very broad question; it depends on the results and on the people discovering them. Some are found by looking at examples and noticing a pattern (it is said that Euler calculated the digits of $\sum_n 1/n^2$ and noticed that they were the same as $\pi^2/6$ before proving the identity; or more generally often conjectures arise this way, like Goldbach's conjecture, or the Riemann hypothesis), but also some are found by studying some already known properties and fiddling around with them (like for instance basic properties of vector spaces or other structures)

Comment: In the case of the logarithm, if I'm not mistaken the first definitions of logarithm had that equation built in : the logarithm of $x$ in base $b$ was "the number of times one has to multiply $b$ by itself to get to $x$", and of course from this your equation follows almost immediately

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\log_b x$ is asking "$b$ to what power equals $x$?" If $b^\bigstar = x$, then surely 
$$b^{n\bigstar} = (b^\bigstar)^n = x^n.$$
This tells us that $$\log_b(x^n) = n \bigstar = n \log_b(x).$$

(I'm assuming above that $b > 1, x > 0$.)

So, facts like this are discovered in part just by understanding what the relevant expressions mean and thinking things through carefully. It always helps to try examples and notice patterns. If a fact is out there waiting to be discovered, and if we search obsessively, eventually we will stumble over the fact and figure out how to understand it.

Comment: Can we consider something to be a "property" if there is no watertight mathematical proof to it?

Comment: Yes, if it's not proved we can't call it a property yet, at best a "conjectured property"

Comment: The word "theorem" means a mathematical fact for which we have an airtight proof, and sometimes the word "property" is used as a synonym for theorem. What somebody calls a "property of logarithms" could equally well be called a "theorem about logarithms".

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_b(b^m)=m\\x=b^z\implies x^n=(b^z)^n\\(b^z)^n=b^{zn}\implies \log_b(x^n)=zn=n\cdot \log_b(x)$$

So if you believe the exponent rules, and know the definition of a log, you get it being forced. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof for more.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not true.

For example, $$\log_2x^2=2\log_2|x|$$ and
$$\log_2x^2\neq2\log_2x.$$
For $x>0$, $b>0$ and $b\neq1$ by the definition of $\log$ we have:
$$b^{\log_b{x^n}}=x^n=\left(b^{\log_bx}\right)^n=b^{n\log_bx}$$ and from here we get the needed property.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question that was actually asked.

Comment: MJD My answer it exectly, which the topic starter looks for. See please better my answer and the definition of log

Answer (score 0):

We observe some regularities and patterns, capture them with definitions, observe dependencies among various definitions and axioms and concepts, and then try to prove or disprove them.

The better you understand some branch the more likely is that you will be able to do a research inside that branch and to discover some laws.

However, it is not easy to master all the branches, some say that Poincare was the last "universalist", meaning that he mastered almost all branches and made an impact in almost all of them.

There are also people, like was Galois, who studied specific general problem and had brilliant ideas that were later successfully generalized and accepted and, if he had more time, probably would also become an "universalist".

The only recipe that I know of on how to discover laws is to have a very good understanding of the definitions, concepts, methods of proof and disproof, and, experimentation can be helpful, especially in number theory.

And how to have a very good understanding is a question that is not always easy to answer.